# Does auto full screen function work on mouse hower?

Tags: automation, fullscreen, build-automation, webkitrequestfullscreen

I was trying to found solution for automation full screen feature. But as I checked it's only work on a appropriate action such as like click or slide up-down. There is any possibility to make this function working on mouse hower or mouse drag.

Show 5 more comments
31

Here is a complete solution to get in and out of full screen mode (aka cancel, exit, escape)

```
    function cancelFullScreen() {
        var el = document;
        var requestMethod = el.cancelFullScreen||el.webkitCancelFullScreen||el.mozCancelFullScreen||el.exitFullscreen||el.webkitExitFullscreen;
        if (requestMethod) { // cancel full screen.
            requestMethod.call(el);
        } else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject !== "undefined") { // Older IE.
            var wscript = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
            if (wscript !== null) {
                wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
            }
        }
    }

    function requestFullScreen(el) {
        // Supports most browsers and their versions.
        var requestMethod = el.requestFullScreen || el.webkitRequestFullScreen || el.mozRequestFullScreen || el.msRequestFullscreen;

        if (requestMethod) { // Native full screen.
            requestMethod.call(el);
        } else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject !== "undefined") { // Older IE.
            var wscript = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
            if (wscript !== null) {
                wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    function toggleFullScreen(el) {
        if (!el) {
            el = document.body; // Make the body go full screen.
        }
        var isInFullScreen = (document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null) ||  (document.mozFullScreen || document.webkitIsFullScreen);

        if (isInFullScreen) {
            cancelFullScreen();
        } else {
            requestFullScreen(el);
        }
        return false;
    }
```